# How to hit non REST endpoints with Ember Data 1.0 beta

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My API is mostly restful except I have a `/search` endpoint on some resources. I'm using the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` and `DS.ActiveModelSerializer` and everything is great.

My current implementation for search is somewhat like this:

```
makeAPICall: ->
  @set('loading', true)

  states = @get('selectedStates')
  statesString = states.join(',')
  query = @get('searchParam')
  url = "/api/v1/organizations/search?#{statesString}&query=#{query}"

  $.get(url).then (data) =>
    @get('store').pushPayload(data)
    # TODO this needs to go through the adapter.
    orgs = data.organizations.map (org) =>
      @store.find('organization', org.id)
    @set('organizations', orgs)
    @set('loading', false)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do all the normalization/camelization that happens in the adapter in this case. Because the template relies on the `@get('organizations')` in this case, some underscored attributes don't show up.

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pushPayload is suposed to do the normalization/camelization but needs to know the type you are pushing, from the docs... but is in the v1.0.0-beta.3 version

```
var pushData = {
  posts: [
   {id: 1, post_title: "Great post", comment_ids: [2]}
  ],
  comments: [
    {id: 2, comment_body: "Insightful comment"}
  ]
}

store.pushPayload('post', pushData);
```

In your case the call should be

```
@get('store').pushPayload('organization', data)
```

And the data json an array of organizations

```
organizations:[
    {id:1,...},
    {id:2,...},
    {id:3,...}
]
```

Comment: And then how would I `@set('organizations')`? I updated the question to show what I'm doing now

Comment: Then you have the organizations in the store, you can find them in your route for example model hook @get('store').find('organization', org.id) but a didn't see your routes definition...

Comment: In this case I don't see how it could happen in the route, but I am doing exactly that in the controller now. I don't love the solution, but it works.

Comment: You can make this method an action of your application route, It will be available from any controller, view with @.send('action',param) or from a template with the {{action ... }} helper